# Why isn't @(DocFileItem) found during MSBuild AfterBuild task?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm trying to post-process the documentation XML file as a post-build XSLT transformation (using the new [XSLTransformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598688.aspx) step), but the build fails with error `Unable to execute transformation. Could not find file 'C:\...\documentation.XML'`. The documentation XML file shows up fine on disk *after* the build is complete, but during the AfterBuild step is simply not there: `<Exec Command="dir $(ProjectDir)$(DocumentationFile)"/>` does not find the file, neither does `<Exec Command="$(ProjectDir)$(DocumentationFile)"/>`.

The XslTransformation step is run from a task named `AfterBuild` and declared as depending of the `Compile` step. Apprently I'm missing something in the way this task is declared so that it does not run before the documentation XML file is complete, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the IDE build system, as per http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/8a2f4af8-7a57-454f-aa7d-684f3f89acf3: the IDE build renames the `$(DocumentationFile)` to .tmp file during the build, and renames it to the proper documentation XML file *after* the build is complete. I can't imagine why would they do that, other than for the personal gratification of an evil project manager who must have now laugh diabolically as it reads this...

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, with this target declaration :

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)$(DocumentationFile)"
        DestinationFolder="C:\..\CopyDirectory"/>
</Target>
```

You should try to remove the dependency on `Compile` step.

Comment: That actually doesn't work for me. Or, to be correct, it always works *once* right after I open the project. The build completes and the files gets copied. But when I build again, I get error `Unabled to copy file... Could not find file...`